# nuget command Source Add started to fail out of nowhere with a warning asking for a unique source

Tags: msbuild, nuget, wix

I have an c# wpf application and an additional installer project to create an installer of the application. Among many other files, the installer project has a installer.cmd file (I took over it from someone else) and a Product.wxs file. I was able to create an installer by running `msbuild tools\installer.cmd /P:Library=net461 /P:Platform=x64` command on the developper comand prompt.
I was trying to create a desktop shortcut in all user's desktops and was playing with *.wxs file for that. I know you guys will roast me because of the following sentence but I don't know what else can I say. Something I did break something and somehow the `msbuild` starts to give error. I cannot say what I did because I tried many different things.. I went back to original project but it didn't help. So what is done is done. I will talk about the error now. 
The error itself doesn't tell much:

```
C:\workspace\QToolInstaller\tools\installer.cmd(117,5): error MSB3073: The command "nuget Source Add -Name PkgSrc_638107674121812897 -Source C:\workspace\QToolInstaller\exports" exited with code 1.
```

I checked online to understand this error code but there wasn't much. However there is another line just before this erorr line:

```
The source specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Provide a unique source.
```

Well, this wasn't in usual warning color or marked as a warning. But I think it is worth to investigate.
So the "source" mentioned here is `PkgSrc_638107674121812897`. I scanned the installer.cmd to see where is this coming form and saw that this file is named by using time ticks as:

```
<LocalSource>PkgSrc_$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Ticks)</LocalSource>
```

Although I ran the `msbuild` command multiple times, the name of the source is always different. I ran the command in diagnostic mode by using `-verbosity:diag` option. And I checked the file name among all the logs. There is no match. I tried to change the name to something ridicolous that cannot be listed anywhere but got the same error. Removed alll the files, created them again, restarted the PC etc. Nothing have changed. This name is really unique and but still I am getting this message. I wish I had logs form previous successfull runs. I cannot tell if this is the cause of the failure or not. Does any of these ring any bell fellas?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved! Luckily a colleague of mine have faced with this before. I hope no one will have to deal with this problem again. 
So apparently there is a bug(?). Altought that name is unique it thinks the opposite. When I do list the sources with thw followng command

```
nuget source
```

among the one that should be there, there is one extra line as `PkgSrc_638107643440982987`. Although my `installer.cmd` suppose to remove the source every time after it is done, it didn't for once. And although the new source is named differently, it doesn't care and gives that non-warning, non-error message followed by a meaningless error code 1 message. How to solve it? 
We tried to remove the source by command prompt like this:

```
nuget source delete -Name PkgSrc_638107643440982987
```

But it is not deleted. So we went to the Visual Studio->Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Settings->Package Sources. Found the guilty source and remove it. And then it is resolved.